# Angular timer is not working

Tags: angularjs, timer, angularjs-directive

Problem statement is timer directive in angular is not working as expected.

I will get the start time in seconds .

My timer looks like this in html:

```js
 $scope.SecondsToMillisecond = function(seconds){

   var   minutes = seconds / 60;
   seconds -= minutes * 60;
   
   var dateObj = new Date(); // current date
   dateObj.setMinutes(parseInt(dateObj.getMinutes() - minutes));
   dateObj.setSeconds(parseInt(dateObj.getSeconds() - seconds));

   var milliseconds = dateObj.getTime();
   return milliseconds;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer" data-ng-init='mSeconds=SecondsToMillisecond(seconds)'>       
  <timer start-time="mSeconds" max-time-unit="'minute'">
 {{mminutes}}:{{sseconds}} 
  </timer>
</div>
```

After execution:
sometimes when seconds exceeds 59 then minutes field instead of setting to 1, it will reset to 0 and in few seconds it will set back to 1 . It's weird but happening.. not getting where I am wrong..

Comment: make mminutes,sseconds with $scope and use in any controller then it will work

Comment: mminutes and sseconds are part of timer directive..I'm getting values but when seconds reaches its max value i.e., 59, instead of setting the minute to 1, it sets to 0 for few seconds and makes it 1..It is not binding problem.

Comment: then without $scope how will you use it

Comment: it belongs to timer directive's scope. so i am getting some value..if i was not getting any value then it would be binding problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending one and half a day, the culprit is finally caught.

There was nothing wrong with the timer directive , but timer was encapsulated within the div tag. div is marked with the class="timer", after removing the timer tag, I found that there is some timer running within the div tag.

Solution is I renamed timer css class and stared working finely.